How to get handler working for post request with axum?
I created a handler function for adding users to my database (using postgres and sqlx).When I isolate the Json input and Extension input, I get successful responses, but when combined as they are in this function, I get an error when calling it from main.rs.
pub async fn create_user_handler(
    Json(payload): Json<User>,
    Extension(db_pool): Extension<PgPool>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    match insert_user(&db_pool, payload).await {
        Ok(user) => {
            let response = ApiResponse::new(user);
            (StatusCode::CREATED, Json(response))
        },
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to insert user: {:?}", e);
            let response = ApiResponse::<User>::from_error("Internal Server Error".to_string());
            (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Json(response))
        },
    }
}

In main:
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(root))
        .route("/api/create-user", post(create_user_handler))
        //.with_state(pool);
        .layer(Extension(pool));

Error message:
.route("/api/create-user", post(create_user_handler))
---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Handler<_, _>` is not implemented for fn item `fn(axum::Json<User>, Extension<Pool<Postgres>>) -> impl Future<Output = impl IntoResponse> {create_user_handler}`

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong here?

Try adding #[debug_handler] to your function to get better diagnostics. Also check the list of requirements for handlers

Json has to go last

@kmdreko that was it!

Also, thanks @cafce25, I didn't know about the debug_handler macro
